# Retrieve files from cloud public folder

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, box-api, onedrive, google-drive-realtime-api

We are creating c# console beta version app for our clients in which they just paste the public folder/file URL of Google drive OR one drive OR drop box OR etc. And in back-end we need to retrieve the file and process it...

I just wanted to know how do we retrieve those cloud files without any prompts for authentication(as given URL will b public, so it should not ask for Id pw)

Any help from you all experts?

Comment: If the URL is public/shared, why are you worried about authentication ?

Comment: Philliph, many of our clients do not have an account on cloud storage. They only have the URL which we emailed them. We do not want them to create an account for this process, or many clients might not use this because they have to create an account..

Comment: Again, ... if the URL is public/shared then why would they require a credential ? Are you saying there is no such thing as a public/shared resource held on Google/Microsoft clouds ? If that is the case then you cannot access such resources without credentials. If you dont want the user to type the credentials you are going to have to hard code them in your app, and handle the postback inside the HttpClient layer yourself.

Comment: I got some sample code in which it first redirected to authentication page :-( to process the public/shared URL also. Do you have some references- how do I hard code credentials n handle the post back...?

Comment: Any examples of Google drive/ one drive/ Dropbox/ etc.

Answer (score 1):

With OneDrive, you can use the ["shares" API](https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm) to retrieve a sharing link without authentication.

You just need to encode the sharing URL correctly and then pass that to the API endpoint. The details of encoding are on the page above, but it's just URL safe base64 encoding.

`GET https://api.onedrive.com/shares/{encoded_sharing_url}/root/content`

The API will return the content of the file.

Edit: I got the URL slightly wrong. The /shares/ API returns a "sharing root" which looks somewhat like a drive object. To access the actual shared file, you need to add /root before the /content part of the path. I've updated this above.

Comment: Ryan, Thanks+1 for Sharing the code snippet url. I tried it, Unfortunately it throwing me an error which i am not able to figure it out :-|, could you please check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you follow the encoding guidelines here: https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm#encoding-sharing-urls ? Otherwise if you can share the code you are using to build the URL I can take a look at what's going wrong.

Comment: Ryan, I have shared my code in this thread only... http://stackoverflow.com/q/37622021/4499378

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake in the URL in my answer. I've edited my answer to correct the mistake and used your code sample to verify that this works with the change. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Hmmm... i still getting the same error (The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request). [Here is my updated code.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kYDJxV)